# ¿Como puedo crear una cola con los valores de una pila?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

¡Hola! Tengo una Pila del tipo **Stack** que almacena objetos, los cuales son categorías de medicamentos. Mi problema es que para cada una de esas categorías/objetos me piden realizar una cola independiente. No sé como hacerlo, ya que las categorías en sí las ingresa el usuario al ejecutar.

```
 public static Stack<Object> Medicamentos = new Stack<>();
 public static void Agregar_Pila(Stack Categorias, Objeto_Medicamentos) {

    Categorias.push(Objeto_Medicamentos);
}
```

Esta es la base con la cual trabajo, probe de distintas maneras pero al instanciar una cola y tratar de segregarlo por tipos lo que hace es crearme una sola pila que almacena todos los medicamentos. ¿Como puedo instanciar una cola con los objetos que el usuario ingresa en la pila?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien la pregunta, el problema es que necesitas una pila para cada categoría, pero las categorías las define el usuario en tiempo de ejecución. En ese caso, lo más fácil sería usar un HashMap.

Asumiendo que tu Objeto_medicamento (a partir de ahora lo voy a llamar Medicamento), tiene un atributo categoría (que en este caso he asumido que es un string, pero podría ser cualquier tipo de objeto), se podría hacer algo como esto:

```java
HashMap<String, Stack<Medicamento>> pilas = new HashMap<String, Stack<Medicamento>>();
public static void Agregar_Pila(Medicamento med) {
    if (!pilas.containsKey(med.categoria)) {
        pilas.put(med.categoria, new Stack<Medicamento>());
    }
    pilas.get(med.categoria).push(med);
}
```

Básicamente, comprobamos si no tenemos una pila para esa categoría, si no la tenemos, creamos una y después añadimos ese medicamento a la pila de su categoría.

Comment: Gracias! Lo he implementado y funcionó de maravilla.